# how can i download a set of variable images in flex/as3 and display them?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

suppose i have 10 image variables like this

var image1:String = http://somewhere.com/image1.jpg
var image2:string = .....image2.jpg
var image3:string = .....image3.jpg
and so forth.........

i have a timer that displays each variable as an image one a time ....

how do i "buffer" the image and display them instead of going out each time the timer runs? im asking because sometimes the server could slow or some other reason. so what i want to do is to download all those images and then display them from the clients computer. some sort like @Embed ???

complete newbie.. so please go slow on me ... :p

Comment: please note that since i cannot post more links as i dont have 10 reputation.....  var image2 , image 3 are all links

eg : somewhere.com/imageX.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how your displaying the images based on the code snippet. However, I assume you are using the image tag and changing the source URL to change the image?

Instead of a bunch of string instances; have you tried a bunch of image instances?  Something like this:

```
var image1 : Image = new Image()
image1.source = 'http://somewhere.com/image1.jpg'
var image2 : Image = new Image()
image2.source = 'http://somewhere.com/image2.jpg'
```

Then you can write some code to display, or not display, the images as appropriate; using a viewStack or other navigator.

Comment: hi jeffrey ... :)

well im displaying the strings with image.source  .... so  i guess its the same thing? ....

Comment: I didn't look up the API before posting; you are correct.  I'll correct the code segment in my answer.